# Running a client-script on loading a webpage

Tags: javascript, ajax, events, browser, protocols

I want to run a script when a user tries to access a webpage.

E.g I type in google.com and as the page loads I want a client side script to
    know the protocol of the page( https in this case).

I know that windows.location.protocol is one way of knowing the protocol in JS.

But how do I make this run when a user accesses a webpage in a browser.

Also can I send a request for a webpage and analyse the response using , say ajax.Suppose I send a http request to facebook. And i get a 301 redirect message.How do I analyse this response and know that this is a redirect message.

Does it require browser modifications?Can it be done without it.Thanks

Comment: Hi Faraz, This can be achieved either by creating browser plugin or by inserting your JS on page which user is going to access.

Answer (score 0):

Like @SachinKumar said...

1) getting and using protocol: create a browser plugin in your preferred browser. Chrome is the most obvious choice.

2) determining response: do you mean, analyze it using your own code when the user receives a 301? (Probably doable with a browser plugin.) Or, do you mean you just want to check the response of some page yourself? (Jquery's http/get functions are one clear way to do that.)